# Datatables Columndef "target" tied to an Editor

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I have this problem in which I have a Datatable with a "columnDefs" attribute that contains 4 column definitions in which each column defines a "target" that calls a column index (i.e "targets": 1). That is fine. However, I also want to create a datatable editor (bubble editor to be exact) that has a "fields" attribute containing "label" and "name". How can I tie up the "label" field of my editor to the datatable which only has "columnDefs" attribute without declaring a "column" attribute ? Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
        ajax: "../php/staff.php",
        table: "#example",
        fields: [ {
                label: "First name:",
                name: "first_name"
```